# word-wrap is not working with the width in percentage

Tags: css, html

I want to align to  next to each other with `width:48%`. If there is text which has no spaces, the string should be broken. Therefore, I added `word-wrap:break-word`.

This won't work. In Chrome, I get this working if I also add `word-break:break-word`. In IE, it would never work.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e02k0d8e/

What do I have to add to .GridRole to get this working in all browsers?
**I do not want to add break-all!**

Comment: Why you don't want to use break-all?

Comment: It would also break words if enough whitespaces are available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way.

Solution 1

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
       word-break: break-all;
```

Solution 2

```
word-break: break-word;
   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   -ms-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario can Handle by the two way.

1) Some charterers after space.

2) Use   `word-wrap:break-all`